# ¿Como comprobar que una fecha se encuentra en un intervalo de fechas con PHP y MYSQLI?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy trabajando en un apartado donde tengo que filtrar fotos dependiendo de los datos que introduzcan en los inputs. Los inputs que tengo son:

- 1 input texto para el titulo
- 2 inputs **date** para establecer un intervalo de búsqueda de fechas de las fotos
- 1 input para seleccionar el país

El caso es que al recoger los datos y hacer la siguiente query:

```
$sentencia = "SELECT fichero, titulo, fecha, pais FROM fotos WHERE titulo LIKE '%$titulo%' OR fecha >= STR_TO_DATE('$desde', '%Y %m %d') AND fecha <= STR_TO_DATE('$hasta', '%Y %m %d') OR pais = '$pais'";
```

**PROBLEMA:** he colocado en los inputs de las fechas unas fechas de ejemplo para comprobar el correcto funcionamiento, pero lo que ocurre es que me trae devuelta todas las fotos, incluso las que tienen la fecha = NULL en la base de datos.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias.

Comment: No se mucho de sql pero no deberías de cambiar los OR por AND ? se supone que los registros deben cumplir las 3 condiciones para poder traerlos o no ?

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Emm, pues... el caso es que mi intención es hacer la query con los campos que se hayan seteado. No sé realmente entonces si la query está mal, o si debería captar cuales son los inputs que están seteados y hacer querys específicas con ellos. ¿Tú que opinas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos a contestarte en dos partes.
Por un lado el `SQL`
El operador lógico **OR**, te devolverá todos los registros que cumplan con CUALQUIERA de las condiciones que pones en la clausula `WHERE`.

El operador lógico **AND** te delvolverá todos los registros que cumplan TODAS las condiciones que pones en la clausula `WHERE`

Con lo que según lo que has puesto, lo mas normal en tu sentencia `SQL` sería

```
$sentencia = "SELECT fichero, titulo, fecha, pais FROM fotos WHERE (titulo LIKE '%$titulo%') AND (fecha >= STR_TO_DATE('$desde', '%Y %m %d') AND fecha <= STR_TO_DATE('$hasta', '%Y %m %d')) AND (pais = '$pais')";
```

Te he colocado los paréntesis en cada condición para que se vea mejor el alcance de cada condición.

Respecto a la **pregunta de tu comentario**, yo personalmente haría una consulta dinámica en función de los campos rellenados por tu usuario con el operador lógico `AND`

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose Javier, finalmente optaré por la opción que me has recomendado: lo solucionaré con la consulta dinámica.